# How can I display an entire message field in Cloudwatch Log Insights, regardless of its length?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Currently, when looking through Insights we have several messages that we'll need to look through but it's not out of the ordinary for some of these messages to be 1000+ characters long. Because of the type of data we process, a lot of times we won't know *exactly* what we're looking for until we see it.

So, let's say that my query gives me 6 results back and all of these results have a message field that's just really long. Is there a way to "word wrap" the results, or show the entire message there on the screen?

I've tried a few things, but honestly nothing has made any difference. The only thing I've found that works is to just select the entire message and then go look at it in Notepad or something. This isn't the worst thing in the world, it'd just make life a little bit easier if I can look at all of the message at one time within the results.